# can somebody tell me the name of the next theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I am looking for the **name** of the next simple fact(theorem):

let $M$ be some matrix and let $k$ be some combinatorial rectangle in $M$. denote the matrix of $k$ by $M_k$.
It holds that:

$Rank(M)\ge Rank(M_k)$

(I can easily prove it. But I want my paper to be brief so I just want to quote this theorem in the paper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this result has a name, but Meyer in his *Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra* states the *Rank and the Largest Nonsingular Submatrix* theorem, from which your result follows easily. See [Section 4.5, page 215](http://www.matrixanalysis.com/DownloadChapters.html).